# How do i define variable within a template cookbook

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I am trying to edit the existing user_management cookbook on the supermarket to include sudoers. I seem to be having problems properly defining the sudoers_groups variable within the template.

Link to default cookbook
https://github.com/FFIN/user_management/blob/master/recipes/default.rb

Here is what my vault looks like.

`knife vault show testusers john`

```
action:       create
comment:      John Smith
dbpass:       secret
gid:          john
id:           john
password:     $1$d$xKNtrFrifo6f7tLFW1xh750
shell:        /bin/bash
sudo_pwdless: true
sudoer:       false
sudoer_group:
  command:      ALL
  name:         admin
  sudo_pwdless: false
  command:      ALL
  name:         wheel
  sudo_pwdless: false
  command:      ALL
  name:         sysadmin
  sudo_pwdless: true
uid:          1002
username:     john`
```

Here is the template section of my recipe

```
sudoer_users = Array.new()
if user['sudoer']
               command = user['command'] ? user['command'] : 'ALL'
               hash = { :uname => user['username'], :command => command, :sudo_pwdless => user['sudo_pwdless'] }
               sudoer_users.push(hash)
        end

template "/etc/sudoers" do
     source 'sudoers.erb'
     mode   '0440'
     owner  'root'
     group  node['root_group']
     variables(
              :sudoers_users     => sudoer_users,
              :sudoers_groups     =>  node[:testcookbook][:testusers][:sudoer_group]
     )
     only_if { sudoer_users }
end
```

When i run the recipe, i get the following error

```
Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/newuser/recipes/default.rb   ============================================.    ====================================    NoMethodError
  -------------`
```

`undefined method [] for nil:NilClass`

`template "/etc/sudoers" do
   61:           source 'sudoers.erb'
   62:           mode   '0440'
   63:           owner  'root'
   64:           group  node['root_group']
   65:           variables(
   66:                    :sudoers_users     => sudoer_users,
   67>>                   :sudoers_groups     =>  node[ :testcookbook][ :testusers][ :sudoer_group]
   68:          )
   69:          only_if { sudoer_users }
   70:  end`

My question is how do i go about defining the sudoers_group variable so that it only iterates  the sudoer_group section within the vault?

Comment: Why not use the sudo cookbook from supermarket to do this too?

Comment: Your issue in the output is due to the line indicated in the output with the >>, `node[ :testcookbook][ :testusers][ :sudoer_group]` - is that defined in your cookbook's attributes as an empty array by default?

Comment: i have this defined in my attributes `default['testcookbook']['testusers']['sudoer_group'] = [ 'sysadmin', 'wheel', 'admin' ]`. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Ruby doesn't give us enough info to check which is undefined, but either `node[:testcookbook]` or `node[:testcookbook][:testusers]` is unset/undefined. Double check where you are setting the `sudoer_group` value because it is likely either misformatted or not uploaded to the Chef Server.

Comment: Any idea how to properly define this in attribute? I currently have it like so `default['testcookbookr']['testusers']['sudoer_group'] = [ 'sysadmin', 'wheel', 'admin' ]`

Comment: `testcookbookr` is typo'd, that's probably it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did to finally resolve the issue.

I added the following as part of my variables in attributes/default.rb.

`default['testcookbook']['testusers']['sudoer_group'] = [`
  `{"name" => "admin", "sudo_pwdless" => false, "command" => "ALL"},`
  `{"name" => "wheel", "sudo_pwdless" => false, "command" => "ALL"},`
  `{"name" => "sysadmin", "sudo_pwdless" => true, "command" => "ALL"}`
]`